# Rename multiple objects in Outliner

Tags: objects, outliner

Is it possible to rename large groups of related objects using a "replace" type capability?

There doesn't appear to be anything in the add-ons for this.

I'd like to be able to add prefixes/suffixes or change a specific characters form "A" to "B".

Thanx in advance for any help.

Comment: As of blender 2.81+, you can select the objects and press `Ctrl` + `F2` to batch rename objects in selection.

Answer (score 16):

You can Batch Rename objects in the Outliner

*Edit > Batch Rename*
Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl + F2</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I am trying to rename an object, its mesh, and its material all at the same time, but the sub-objects aren't recognized as objects for renaming?

Comment: @endolith That's right :). The sub-objects are called meshes, and are renamed separately. You can choose in the rename menu whether it applies to objects/meshes/materials...

Comment: Oh, it can only apply to one or the other?  Hmm.  Is it not good practice to name them the same or something?

Comment: I can't test right now, whether you can rename both objects and meshes at once :). But I often name objects and meshes the same and never had any problems :)

Comment: CTRL F2 does'nt do anything (v2.91)

Comment: hey @phil123 :). it's also under Edit > Batch Rename

Comment: I had no idea this was a thing, and this is awesome. Saved me a ton of time renaming all my objects/collections today. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Marty, glad it helped :))